# Are two events with non zero probability of occurence and empty intersection independent

Tags: probability

Given two events $A, B$ of which the first is the outcome of flipping a coin and the second is the outcome of a weather forcasting, one will intuitively say that the two events are independent, since the outcome of $A$ in no way would effect the outcome of $B.$ So one could write $P(A|B)=P(A).$ But then I have a problem which is: from the independence must follow $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B).$ I guess $A\cap B=\emptyset $ since I dont see what the two events can have in common and so $0=P(A)P(B),$ where $P(A), P(B)$ must not be zero.

What is wrong in these thoughts ? Are two events which have empty intersection independent if the probability of each is non zero ?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure I understand the confusion here.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen. I wrote $P(A), P(B)$ are non zero and I repeted it again the text. I read your answer in the ''duplicate'' Question where you are comparing the outcome of two rolling dice. Why are the events $A, B$ as stated in my question not Independent but rather exclusive events?

Comment: Sorry about the misread. New Year's Eve party fog. Why do you think that the event of both the coinflip giving *tails* and the weather forecast saying *sunny* is empty? Imagine that every morning you flip a coin and read the forecast. Sooner rather than later you get "tails" and "sunny" on the same day. That's not an empty set!

Comment: To continue the analogy with dice. Here your coinflip has the role of rolling a red die and the weather forecast is rolling a green die. The outcomes of the two rolls are independent. And $P(R5\ \text{and}\ G6)=P(R5)\cdot P(G6)$. On the other hand, the events *red $5$* and *red $6$* are mutually exclusive and have an empty intersection.

Comment: Or yet in other words, you were thinking about the intersection in *the wrong space.* Your universe $\Omega$ consists of **pairs**
$$\Omega=\{(a,b)\mid \text{$a$ is the result of a coinflip},\ \text{$b$ is the weather forecast}\}.$$ So $\Omega$ has elements like (heads, sunny), (tails, sunny), (heads, rainy), (tails, rainy) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that mutually exclusive events are necessarily independent. That is not the case as you have mentioned one is about $P(A\cap B)=0$ and the other one about $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$

Comment: Many thanks. To put it short, are the events $A, B$ exclusive or indepenedent without taking into consideration my assumption that $A\cap B=\emptyset$ ?

Comment: $P(A\cap B)=0 $ is the mutual exclusive case in which the events are dependent unless both have zero probability.

Comment: Ok. But how can the two events $A, B$ (coin flipping and weather forcasting) be dependent ? This is the core of the problem which I dont understand.

Comment: They are independent and they are not mutually exclusive. If probability of rain in one day is 1/3 and you flip a coin then probability of both raining and getting a head is (1/3)(1/2)=1/6.

Comment: Main mistake is the assumption that the events are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have $P(A), P(B) > 0$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset \implies P(A \cap B) = 0$.

This is not what was call "independent," but rather "mutually exclusive" - only one of $A,B$ can occur. You can heuristically look at this is an extreme sort of dependence - they are dependent in that if one occurs, then the other cannot.

Comment: I wrote, $P(A|B)=P(A)$ and thus I concluded $A,B$ are independent. So no matter what my comment on $A, B$ was, are $A, B$ as events independent or not ? Is my Statement $A\cap B= \emptyset$ true or false ?

Comment: Recall: 

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

If $P(A \cap B) = 0$, $P(A|B) = 0$. However, $P(A) > 0$. Thus, $P(A|B) \neq P(A)$.

Comment: Given the two events $A,B$ as described above is then $A\cap B=\emptyset $ false ?

Comment: It can happen that the coin gives "heads" and the weather forcast gives "rain". So events like that are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

No, such events are dependent (in extrem way). Events $A$ and it negation $A'$ are disjunct but they are (very) dependent. If one hapens the other does not.

Comment: Thanks. I dont understand what is the negation event in my case. Let say the Event $A$ has a certain outcome. What do you mean by saying that the other does not happen ?

Answer (score 0):

In a suitable model of reality in the form of a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ the described events $A$ and $B$ will be both subsets of the $\sigma$-algebra that is in use.

Further the probability measure that is in use will - if it indeed models reality on a suitable  way - give: $$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$$

The event $A\cap B$ will - if $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are both positive - *not be empty*.

If e.g. $(\Omega_1,\mathcal A_1,P_1)$ models the coin-flipping and $(\Omega_2,\mathcal A_2,P_2)$ models the weather forcasting then go for the product of both probability spaces.